# How to set a div class depending on a variable value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to set a div class depending on a variable that is set by another process.

The reason for this is I am trying to create a dashboard type page to show if certain servers are up or down among other things.

If there is a better way of doing this I am happy to try a completely different option.

Code (from comment):

```
<script>
    var server.v1 = "Down" 
</script>
<script>
    var servers.v2 = "Up" 
</script> 
<div id=servers> 
<script>
    if document.getElementById("servers").innerHTML = v2 == up {
         div class="ComponentSuccess"
    } else {
         div class="ComponentFail"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this than...? It would help a lot if we could see the code you're using now.

Comment: You need to show what you have attempted

Comment: I have two div classes set and at the moment what I have come up with after much searching is...

Comment: <script>var server.v1 = "Down" </script><script>var servers.v2 = "Up" </script>
<div id=servers> <script>if document.getElementById("servers").innerHTML = v2 == up {div class="ComponentSuccess"} else {div class="ComponentFail"}</script>

Comment: I added your code from comment to the question, which may be missing parts, but it has so many errors I don't know where to start. Where did you get that code? Can you complete it *in the question*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, as you tagged the question with, it's pretty straight forward

```
var $myDiv = $(/* get your div */);
var isValid = /* your code here to check */
var className = isValid? 'valid' : 'invalid';
$myDiv.addClass(className);
```

Obviously this is simplified example, you'll probably want to toggle the class and make sure it doesn't get both classes and so on.

Comment: You may wish to update your answer based on the mess of code that has been added. They have *many* problems.